# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessClassInPackage.sun.misc)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, tomcat

So my hosting company changed their service to tomcat 7 with security manager, and from that time on I am getting this exception every time my application tries to connect to MySQL database with Hibernate. I don't know what to do, they ask me for my Tomcat permissions, but I have not defined anything special.

Can any one help me?

This is my stack trace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:862)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.access$1100(PageContextImpl.java:71)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl$12.run(PageContextImpl.java:778)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:776)
    org.apache.jsp.news_jsp._jspService(news_jsp.java:285)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)


root cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    ir.omicc.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    ir.omicc.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    ir.omicc.classes.Publisher.getNews(Publisher.java:126)
    org.apache.jsp.news_jsp._jspService(news_jsp.java:221)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)

root cause



java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission hibernate.enable_specj_proprietary_syntax read)
    java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
    java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:650)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:362)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:296)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:300)
    ir.omicc.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ir.omicc.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    ir.omicc.classes.Publisher.getNews(Publisher.java:126)
    org.apache.jsp.news_jsp._jspService(news_jsp.java:221)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:269)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:301)
    org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:162)
```

Comment: that's the same problem, your package ir.omicc... (which jar is it ?) do have the security access from catalina.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem in your tomcat security configuration.
Check if exists in ${catalina.home}/conf/catalina.policy
the following lines :

```
grant {

    // Precompiled JSPs need access to this package.
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessClassInPackage.sun.misc.*";
};
```

and add in ${catalina.home}/conf/policy.d/03.catalina.policy

```
// The permissions granted to your jar (ir.omicc ??)
grant codeBase "file:/path/to/the/ir.omicc.utilBox/your.jar" {
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

it's a workaround but it's not secure.

Comment: but it is not all about that jar file, every time i try to connect database , this problem occurs

Comment: it's all about your classes in that jar file, your jar do have the permission to other resources

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the class `ir.omicc.utilBox.PasswordService` tries to use some class in the `sun.misc` package. If this class is one of your classes, then you should reimplement it without accessing the sun.misc classes. If not, then ask the developer/company who implemented this class to fix it. Using `sun.misc` classes is a very bad practice, which has always been discouraged.

Comment: humm, i am using that to encrypt passwords, but it is not that, because i get this error every time i try to connect to database , even without the use of this class

Answer (score 1):

I asssume the stack trace has been edited. You now need to grant your codebase the following permission:

```
java.util.PropertyPermission "hibernate.enable_specj_proprietary_syntax", "read";
```

or more probably "hibernate.*", "read, write";

Comment: yes i edited the trace, but i wrote "edited" too :-? i think this will solve it, let me try it

Comment: i did what you said and error changed! i am now getting this one : java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)