# howto use CGLIB proxy in spring on GAE?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, aop, cglib

I'm trying to configure my app to use CGLIB proxy on GAE

according to docs
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html I've set in my applicationContext.xml the attribute proxy-target-class attribute of the  element to true

```xml
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="advice1" pointcut="execution(* org.somepackage.*.*(..))" />
  <aop:advisor advice-ref="advice1" pointcut="execution(* org.somepackage.someclass.*(..))" />
</aop:config>
```

But I'm still receiving this error:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
    ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.proxy")
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-c6d418658e01b411(Request.java)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:382)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:572)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:147)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegateFactory.createDelegate(ReflectionBasedReferenceTypeDelegateFactory.java:40)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld.resolveDelegate(ReflectionWorld.java:110)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:378)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:271)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:191)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:338)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.couldMatchJoinPointsInType(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:76)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:235)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:195)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:250)
```

Where I'm wrong?

Comment: Looks like you need to grant access to some classes or packages in your security configuration, se [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173989/java-security-accesscontrolexception-access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission). But maybe you are also just experiencing this [problem on Google side](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000999/java-google-app-engine-failed-at-startup-permission-denied).

Comment: in the first case I don't know where adding a policy file on GAE, in the second case I don't know how ask a downgrado to Google like Mauro has done...

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) as a minimal showcase, ideally with a Maven build, preferably on GitHub.